# In Angular 11, how do you set a timer with RXJS (e.g. avoid "TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected" errors)

Tags: angular, timer, rxjs, angular11

I just recently upgraded to Angular 11.2.9 and RXJS 6.6.7 .  I have this in my component ...

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    window.addEventListener('blur', this.onBlur, false);
    ...
  }
  ...



  onBlur(): void {
    this.trendingSet$ = timer(1, HotComponent.REFRESH_INTERVAL_IN_MS).pipe(
      switchMap(() => this.apiService.getTrending()),
      retry(),
      share(),
      takeUntil(this.stopPolling)
    );
    console.log(this.trendingSet$);
    this.trendingSet$.subscribe((result: TrendingSet) => {
      this.articleStats = result.trending_articles;
    });
  }
```

However, I'm getting this error on the

```
this.trendingSet$.subscribe((result: TrendingSet) => {
```

line:

```
ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    RxJS 4
    onBlur hot.component.ts:90
    Angular 14
    ngOnInit hot.component.ts:35
    Angular 21
    RxJS 5
    Angular 8
        emit
        checkStable
        onHasTask
        hasTask
        _updateTaskCount
        _updateTaskCount
        runTask
        drainMicroTaskQueue
core.js:6210
    Angular 3
    RxJS 5
    Angular 20
    RxJS 10
    onBlur hot.component.ts:90
    Angular 14
    ngOnInit hot.component.ts:35
    Angular 21
    RxJS 5
    Angular 8
```

What's the proper way to set a timer in my component to regular query a service method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use **window.addEventListener('blur', this.onBlur, false)** when you have rxjs wrapped fromEvent...

The initial problem here is that when you call onBlur as a callback to 'blur' event, pointer **this** (in **this**.trendingSet$) will point to Window object and not your component, in that case you have to use **window.addEventListener('blur', this.onBlur.bind(this), false)**

Also, **share** operator is redundant here unless you are using stream **this.trendingSet$** on other places as well

**EDIT**

```
private startPolling$ = new Subject();
private stopPolling$ = new Subject();

// Using this logic, subscription to blur event will be automatically unsubscribed once Component is being destroyed
@HostListener('window:blur', ['$event'])
onBlurEvent(): void {
    this.startPolling$.next();
}

ngOnInit() {

    const poll$ = timer(1, HotComponent.REFRESH_INTERVAL_IN_MS)
        .pipe(switchMap(() => this.apiService.getTrending()), retry());

    this.startPolling$.pipe(
        switchMap(() => poll$),
        takeUntil(this.stopPolling$)
    ).subscribe((response) => {
        // Doing stuff with response
    });
}
```

Or instead of using **@HostListener** you can use

```
    const poll$ = timer(1, HotComponent.REFRESH_INTERVAL_IN_MS)
        .pipe(switchMap(() => this.apiService.getTrending()), retry(), 
        takeUntil(this.stopPolling$));

    fromEvent(document, 'blur').pipe(
       switchMap(() => poll$),
   ).subscribe((response) => {
      // Doing stuff with response
   });
```

Comment: You say to not use 'window.addEventListener('blur', this.onBlur, false)' but what is the alternative?